# Is it possible to synchronize HLS livestreaming between devices?

Tags: android, synchronization, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I have a HLS livestream set up with a 2-second segment length, and two devices to play it with - two Android phones with Exoplayer.

When I start the playback in both Android phones (one with mobile data, one with Wi-fi), for some reason the device connected to the Wi-fi is 2 seconds ahead of the one using mobile data (I noticed it's a one-segment difference).

Is it possible to have both devices (this extending to all the other devices playing that HLS stream) to have their playbacks begin synchronous to the other devices' playbacks, as in, start at the exact same live edge, or is it too much to ask for a HLS stream?

EDIT: Is the HLS tag `EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME` a viable way to synchronize between devices' playbacks?

Comment: Hi, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

**DefaultLoadControl** waits until it has 5 seconds of buffered media before continuing playback.

You can try to change bufferForPlayBackMs and bufferForPlaybackAfterRebufferMs to 0. I didn't test it.

```
DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder().setBufferDurationsMs(minBufferMs, maxBufferMs, bufferForPlaybackMs, bufferForPlaybackAfterRebufferMs).createDefaultLoadControl();
```

Comment: Already tried that with 3000 `minBufferedMs`, 4000 `maxBufferedMs`, 0 `bufferForPlaybackMs`, and 0 `bufferForPlaybackAfterRebufferMs`. I could go for 1000-2000 `bufferedMs`, but that will just make the stream buffer more often.